# How do i generate a random UUID in xquery

Tags: xquery, uuid

Can anyone help me with this one? I want to be able to generate a random UUID in x-query. Is there any function to do this?

thanks!

Comment: What XQuery processor are you using? Many have built-in UUID-generating functions.

Comment: I am using this library: net.sf.saxon.javax.xml.xquery.*;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Saxon, you should be able to link to Java to generate the UUIDs like this:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:uuid="java:java.util.UUID">
```

**XQuery**

```
declare namespace uuid = "java:java.util.UUID";
```

Then call the function `uuid:randomUUID()` anywhere in the stylesheet or XQY script.

Comment: This seems like a solution in xslt. I was actually looking for a solution in xquery. Thanks!

Comment: This is basically the same, i.e. ````declare namespace uuid=java:java.util.UUID````

Comment: @ridermule Sorry, that's true. Dirk's response is correct - the same thing is happening under the hood. See the updated example.

Comment: Hi dirkk and wst, I tried this and this solution worked amazingly!!!!! I cannot thank you guys enough!

Answer (score 0):

`fn-bea:uuid()` is also an option for those who use BEA's xQuery implementation. 
For example, when writing xQuery for Oracle Service Bus (OSB) Framework.